# Complex Statements Intent Classification

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, azure-language-understanding, wit.ai

Consider following sentences:
1) I want to watch movies watched by Srikanth but not by tarun
2) I want to watch movies of Christoper Nolan but not having Christian Bayle
3) I want watch movies watched by Srikanth but not liked by Tarun

The problem I am facing is - 
Even though I can successfully define entities such as "not watched", "watched" , "not liked" , "having" , "not having" etc; etc;
Hence I will know what kind of action user is referring to. 
I will also get to know names like Srikanth, Tarun, Nolan, Bayle etc;
But How do I establish Relationship between name and action. How do i know which action was related to which name.
I am not able to achieve this in LUIS / DIALOGFLOW.

What I feel is only way is to break statement into 2 distinct statements, How can we do that and is that a right approahc

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly assign multiple intents to the same utterance through LUIS. You can use NLTK along with LUIS to fix this issue as discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1731).

Another workaround is to create 2 apps with each intent and assign the same utterances and add the code which would differentiate the intent based on the keyword in the sentence.